# Parse string using newline delimiter then assign to variables

Tags: go, string-parsing

I am trying to parse serial input into sentences, then assign those sentences to a variable. Here is an example of what I am trying to do. My serial port currently outputs this:

```
This is the first sentence. 
This is the second sentence. 
This is the third sentence.
```

I read this in and print it by using:

```
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(port)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
        }
```

What I would like to do is I want to assign each sentence to a **new variable**. I want to later do something like this (example):

```
fmt.Printf("First sentence: %q\n", firstSen)
fmt.Printf("Second sentence: %q\n", secondSen)
fmt.Printf("Third sentence: %q\n", thirdSen)
```

And it should output:

```
First sentence: This is the first sentence. 
Second sentence: This is the second sentence. 
Third sentence: This is the third sentence.
```

How can do I go about doing this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Collect the lines from the input:

```
var lines []string
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(port)
for scanner.Scan() {
    lines = append(lines, scanner.Text())
}
if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
    // handle error
}
```

Loop through variables assigning a line to the variable:

```
var firstSen, secondSen, thirdSen string
for i, s := range []*string{&firstSen, &secondSen, &thirdSen} {
    if i >= len(lines) {
        break
    }
    *s = lines[i]
}
```

Print as shown in the question:

```
fmt.Printf("First sentence: %q\n", firstSen)
fmt.Printf("Second sentence: %q\n", secondSen)
fmt.Printf("Third sentence: %q\n", thirdSen)
```

Depending on your requirements, you can drop the variables and use the slice of lines directly:

```
fmt.Printf("First sentence: %q\n", line[0])
fmt.Printf("Second sentence: %q\n", line[1])
fmt.Printf("Third sentence: %q\n", line[2])
```

Comment: Thanks! Although I'm faced with a problem right now. It seems like nothing gets printed if I use either of the two methods. Maybe this has something to do with taking input through the serial port?

Comment: Use [iotest.NewReadLogger](https://godoc.org/testing/iotest#NewReadLogger) to log the data read from the port. `scanner := bufio.NewScanner(iotest.NewReadLogger("port", port))`.  Debug from there if it's not what you expect.